# Creating a ranked list based on proportions in R

Tags: r, ranking

I am looking to create a priority list for locations that is proportional to location types.

```
data <- data.frame("locationNumber" = 1:12, "type" = c("hill","hill","hill","forest","forest","hill","hill","hill","forest","grass","hill","forest"))

#calculate proportions per type                                    
proportions <- data %>%
   dplyr::group_by(type) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(freq = round(n / sum(n),2))
```

[image: thinking about it in excel]

Above are the proportions per type for 1-4 locations as an example.To determine the first priority location you would multiple the "freq" by 1.  Since the hill type has the largest number (0.58) the first hill location (number 1 in the locationNumber column) would have a priority of 1.  To determine the second priority location you would multiple the "freq" by 2. Since you already have a hill location (priority 1) you would subtract 1 from 1.16 and be left with .16. Since .66 is the largest number left the second priority location would be the first forest location (number 4 in the locationNumber column).  And so on until you have a prioritized list 1-12. If there is a tie (as there is when you get to 4) the tie breaker would be to prioritize the location with the smallest proportion.

expected output:
[image: expected output]

Comment: the first image is not matching with the values from proportions

Comment: Can you pleease check your example with 'proportion'

Comment: Can you explain few more calculations for other values?

Comment: thanks for taking a look-  To determine the third priority location you would multiple 3 times the freq (as seen in the column "3" in the excel picture above.  Since the forest type already as one location ranked you would subtract 1 from .99.  Since grass has no locations ranked yet it would stay at .24 and since there is one ranked hill location you would subtract 1 from 1.74. So now you are comparing -0.01, .24, and .74 so the third priority location will be a hill location with the second lowest locationNumber (locationNumber 2)

Comment: To get the forth priority location you multiple 4 times the freqs and repeat the subtraction process based on how many locations of each type are already assigned.  In this case subtract 1 from forest and 2 from hill.  Since you are left with a tie (.32) for all three types the 4th priority ranking would go to grass using the lowest proportion tie break rule. @RonakShah

Comment: The first image is a screenshot of looking at the proportions and subsequent steps in excel.   the proportions value from the code would be:                                                   
 ` type       n  freq
1 forest     4 0.33 
2 grass      1 0.08 
3 hill       7 0.580
`